# how to coexist interbase 6 and firebird 1.5 in linux?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, firebird, interbase

I installed the superserver IB6 in ubuntu 12.04, it works, then I installed firebird classic 1.5, set its port to 3051, but before starting FB1.5, IB6 server can not be started any more : sudo /opt/interbase/bin/ibmgr -start,
it seems that FB installed its own version of libgds.so replacing IB6's libgds.so, if I copy back IB6's libgds.so, ibmgr will start, any idea how to achieve the co-existence of the two? Thanks,

Comment: even on Windows co-existence and simultaneous execution of different FB 1.x and IB 6.x versions is non-trivial http://www.ibase.ru/inst_manual/#anchor_2run  // you best options would be creating two separate Linux virtual machines (OpenVZ, QEMU, etc) and installing different servers into those

Comment: InterBase 6 is 18 years old, and Firebird 1.5 is not much younger. Why are you even running these ancient versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work, you should set up FB first, then IB later,
reason is the /usr/libgds.so,  FB will point it to its version, FB server seems
not using libgds, but IB ibmgr uses client API which depends on libgds, installing IB6 after FB will point the libgds to the IB version, the steps are:

1) install fb, set port number to 3051
2) install IB, keep its original port (3050)

this works.